# Can I add a button below the native decimal keyboard pad in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, ios-keyboard-extension

Is there way to add a button below the native keyboard in SwiftUI? The button should be pinned to the bottom of the keyboard per requirements.
Looks like the `ToolbarItemGroup` can only pin items to the top of the keyboard. I've searched around and doesn't look like this is possible without building a custom keyboard?

I've attached an image of what I'd like to build below:

[image]

Comment: No, can't be done in SwiftUI or UIKit.